# $x_n - x_{n-2} \to 0$, how to prove that the limit of $(x_n - x_{n-1})/n$ is zero?

Tags: limits

A sequence of real number $\langle x_n \rangle_{n \in \mathbb N_+}$ satisfies that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n - x_{n-2}) = 0$.
Please prove that
$$
    \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n - x_{n-1}}{n} = 0.
$$

I tried to use O. Stolz's theorem so that
$$
    \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n - x_{n-1}}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} (x_{n+1} - 2x_n + x_{n-1}),
$$
but I failed to find the way to utilize the condition that $x_n - x_{n-2} \to 0$.

Comment: Hint:  Show that the sequence $x_{2n}$ converges to a number and the sequence $x_{2n+1}$ also converges to a (posssibly different) number.

Comment: @Alan I don't think that's going to be true in general, for example if $x_n = (-1)^n \log n$.

Comment: I think if you apply the Cesaro-Stolz theorem to the Cesaro sum of $x_{2n} - x_{2n-2}$ you should get $\frac{x_{2n}}{n} \to 0$ and similarly $\frac{x_{2n-1}}{n} \to 0$.

Comment: Woops, forgot they could both grow slower and slower.  Would need to be modified.  And @ThomasAndrews why wouldn't that converge when divided by $n$?

Comment: Oh, yeah, forgot the division by $n.$ Deleting.

Comment: @abiessu did you forget about the division by $n?$ Hard to tell, since you chose $x$ as your variable.

Comment: @thomasandrews yep, that's a solid reason for my example to not work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_i\to L$ then: $$b_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$$ converges to $L,$ too. (This is a common result. It is the first application of the Stolz-Cesàro theorem at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem), but it is also a common exercise in analysis.)

Let $a_n=x_{2n+2}-x_{2n}.$ Then $a_n\to 0.$ Here, $$b_n=\frac{x_{2n+2}-x_{2}}{n}\to 0$$ But since $\frac{x_{2}}n\to 0,$ this means $\frac{x_{2n+2}}{n}\to0.$

Similarly, from $a_n’=x_{2n+1}-x_{2n-1},$ you get $\frac{x_{2n+1}}n\to 0.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I would like to add a note: if $z_{2k}$ and $z_{2k+1}$ has a same limit $a$, then $z_n$ must converge to the same limit too. $\forall \varepsilon \in \mathbb R_+$, we can find $N_1$ for $z_{2k}$ and $N_2$ for $2k+1$ such that $\forall k > \max\{N_1, N_2\}$ ($n > \max\{2N_1, 2N_2+1\}$), $|z_n - a| < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $M_N=\sup\{|x_{n}-x_{n-2}|:n>2N\}$.
Then
$$ |x_{2k}-x_{2N}|\le M_N(k-N)<M_Nk$$
and
$$ |x_{2k-1}-x_{2N-1}|\le M_N(k-N)<M_Nk$$
for $k>N$, thus for $n=2k$ making for
$$\left|\frac{x_{n}-x_{n-1}}{n}\right|\le\frac{M_Nk+M_Nk+|x_{2N}-x_{2N-1}|}{n} $$
and similarly for odd $n$. As the right hand side $\to M_N$ and we can make $M_N$ small by making $N$ big, the claim follows.